# The code did not run with the super()__init__

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the classes on python, I'm also trying to use the super () __ init__ command to inherit all the values ​​of the previous class, only it gives me an error when compiling and I don't know how to systemize the code .
The code is executable! Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
class rectangle:
def __init__(self, length, height):
    self.length = length
    self.height = height

def area(self):
    return self.length * self.height
def perimeter(self):
    return (self.length *2) + (self.height *2)
class square(rectangle):
def __init__(self, length):
    super().__init__(rectangle, self)
rett_1 = rectangle("12","3")
print(rectangle.area(rett_1))
```

The error that python give me also is that:

```
    return self.length * self.height
```

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: A square with length L is a rectangle L x L -->  `super().__init__(length, length)`

Comment: `rectangle` doesn't inherit from anything... and the error is because you are trying to multiple strings.

Comment: And these are strings, not numbers: `rectangle("12","3")`

Comment: Why are your lengths strings?

Comment: sorry, the sqare have to inherit the class from rectangle instance

Comment: i don't understand why my lenght came out as a string

Comment: Because you are sending it as a string.

Comment: Okya, now i will try fixing the code sending as output as a numeric value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the answer was on the final part of the code:

```
rett_1 = rectangle(12, 3)
print(rectangle.area(rett_1))
```

i had to remove the "" on the number that i want to insert.